# TWRP crashes on Redmi Note 8 Pro after custom rom

Tags: custom-roms, twrp, lineageos

I tried to root my phone and succeeded without any errors, then I wanted to try installing a Custom ROM(lineageOS), I did it via TWRP(I forgot to reinstall TWRP before rebooting) then I tried to boot again to TWRP(as expected it was gone) then I reinstalled TWRP via fastboot(`fastboot flash recovery filename.img`), the command exited without any errors but when I tried to boot to recovery nothing shows up:

• Black Screen

• After a few seconds reboots back to lineage

I downloaded the latest TWRP image from the official Website and tried to install that, same command, install success and able to boot to TWRP

BUT after a few seconds in TWRP mode(idle or not) it closes and reboots back to lineage

What I tried:

• Installing older TWRP version

• `adb erase recovery` and reinstall

Notes:

• Lineage OS works as expected

***EDIT***

I haven't mentioned it but what i need the most is a way to install zip files from fastboot, i can extract the zip but some OSes have system.new.dat.something and i cannot find a way to install that, if you could at least help mart with this i'd be greatful.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/unofficial-rom-cwf-begonia-twrp-deployment-lineageos-from-theimpulson.4270573

Answer (score 0):

it is because the lineage os you're running came shipped with lineage os recovery and now the partition is someway corrupted while you tried to install twrp.

try booting to lineage turning adb on and from your computer using platform tools, execute `adb shell reboot recovery`

Comment: I am aware of lineage os's recovery but that's not the case, i tried to ```adb erase recovery``` and reinstall but didn't work

Comment: you disabled verified boot too before trying to install twrp ?

Comment: get vbmeta.img and `fastboot --disable-verity --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.img`  then flash twrp

Comment: ```fastboot --disable-verity --disable-verification flash vmbeta vbmeta.img``` throws an error, disable verity is not recognised as an option, nor disable verification.

Comment: You are using wrong fastboot. Download latest platform-tools from google https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads

Comment: @Vbrawl yeah get  latest platform tools

Comment: That killed me, now the phone won't enter fastboot at all

Comment: ok got it unbricked but still the recovery doesn'f work